# Rest of the division in python

Tags: python

when I calculate the rest of the division in python, I get answers like this:

```
>>> 12,121123123 % 10
(12, 3)
>>> 12,333434 % 5
(12, 4)
>>> 14,54 % 4
(14, 2)
```

I would like to understand what means this ordered pair.

Comment: @Daniel - I think this question is about the tuples, rather than what `%` means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`14,54` is not a decimal number. It is a *2-element tuple* containing the integers `14` and `54`.

If you want to specify a decimal number, you have to use the decimal point `.`:

```
>>> 12.121123123 % 10
2.1211231230000003
>>> 12.333434 % 5
2.3334340000000005
>>> 14.54 % 4
2.539999999999999
```

Otherwise, your code is equivalent to this:

```
>>> (12, 121123123 % 10)
(12, 3)
>>> (12, 333434 % 5)
(12, 4)
>>> (14, 54 % 4)
(14, 2)
```

And there, each tuple element is evaluated separately, so for `(14, 54 % 4)`, you get back the 2-tuple with the elements `14` and the result of `54 % 4`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use dot `.` instead of comma `,`. When you use comma, then you have tuple of objects, not a number.